# php,laravel. how to use {!! $data !!} this syntax in image tag in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, image, syntax

blade

how to use {!! $front_img !!} In image src for example

```
<img src="{{asset('hash images/project images/frontend/.!!$front_img!!')}}" alt="front">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
<img src="{{asset("hash images/project images/frontend/.$front_img")}}" alt="front">
```

Or

```
<img src="{{asset('hash images/project images/frontend/.'.$front_img)}}" alt="front">
```